# Symfony2 HWIOAuthBundle Yahoo login error

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, yahoo, hwioauthbundle

I have a login page with OAuth authentication (FOSUserBundle + HWIOAuthBundle). It's working with Google and Facebook.

When I try to login with my Yahoo account, I'm just redirected to my login page with no error. If I click at Google or Facebook buttons, I'm redirected to the permission page normally.

I see no reason for problems, and do not understand why there are no exceptions.

At config.yml:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: main
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            facebook: facebook
            google:   google
            yahoo:    yahoo

    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           my_f_cid
            client_secret:       my_f_sk
            scope:               "email"

        yahoo:
            type:                yahoo
            client_id:           my_y_cid
            client_secret:       my_y_sk
            scope:               "email"

        google:
            type:                google
            client_id:           my_g_sid
            client_secret:       my_g_sk
            scope:               "email"
```

At security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider:      fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path:    /login
                check_path:    /login_check

            oauth:
                failure_path: /login
                login_path:   /login
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:   "/login/check-facebook"
                    google:     "/login/check-google"
                    yahoo:      "/login/check-yahoo"
```

At routing.yml:

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /login

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /login

hwi_facebook_login:
    pattern:  /login/check-facebook

hwi_google_login:
    pattern:  /login/check-google

hwi_yahoo_login:
    pattern:  /login/check-yahoo
```

The login buttons:

```
<a id="btn-facebook" href="http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/login/facebook">
    <img src="/bundles/auth/images/social_login_facebook.png">
</a>
<a id="btn-google" href="http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/login/google">
    <img src="/bundles/auth/images/social_login_google.png">
</a>
<a id="btn-yahoo" href="http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/login/yahoo">
    <img src="/bundles/auth/images/social_login_yahoo.png">
</a>
```

Comment: do you find answer for this problem?

Comment: @ghanbari I gave up on the Yahoo login at that time. I have not tried again with the same configuration.